# How to create a new column to calculate percentage weight of a value in power bi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to achieve Percentage_weight from 4 different columns of a table into a new column. This is what I can do in Excel `=SUM((D2*0.2)+(E2*0.25)+(F2*0.25)+(G2*0.3))`.

How do we do the same calculations in Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `% Weight = ([ColumnA]*0.2)+([ColumnB]*0.25)+([ColumnCA]*0.25)+([ColumnD]*0.3)`
just change the column Name/refences. No need to use the SUM unless you're doing a dynamic measure

Comment: Great :) please tag it as an answer and upvote if possible :D cheers